# laravel routing mp4 video not playing on iphone

Tags: laravel, local-storage, html5-video

I have a youtube style website, some videos are private and are in local storage disk.

> storage/app/videos/channel_name/filename.mp4

I have the generated thumbnails in the local storage as well, the thumbnails will show but the videos will not play, do I have to do anything different for mobile?

View

```
 <video width="100%" id="main_video" controls>
      <source src="{{ route('getVideo', ['video'=> $video->video_upload_id])  }}" type="video/mp4" >
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

Route

```
Route::get('get-video/{video}', 'WatchController@getVideo')->name('getVideo');
```

Controller

```
/**
 * @param VideoUpload $video
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getVideo(VideoUpload $video)
{
    $channel_name = Session::get('channel');

    $file_name = $video->video_file_name;

    $fileContents = \Storage::disk('local')->get("videos/$channel_name/$file_name");

    $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200);

    $response->header('Content-Type', "video/mp4");

    return $response;

}
```

everything is working ok on desktop, any ideas? thanks

Comment: Can you check if this thread [here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/929) can help. There are some additional properties from which you have `controls` but without the `true` value.

Comment: dd($response) also print from the inspect view

Comment: sorted, thank you, i just converted the video into a blob